# Does python polars have a native way to store attributes?

Tags: python, attributes, python-polars

I'm regularly working with unique, non-repeating data often found in CSV files or dataframes, and these are considered as attributes of the dataframe.

For instance, I might have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
})
```

And the associated attributes are stored in JSON format:

```
{
    "source": "dataset.csv",
    "created_on": "2023-07-06",
    "unique_identifier": "ABC123"
}
```

While PyArrow has the ability to store these attributes in a Parquet file, I haven't yet used it for this particular application due to the complexity and convolution of the documentation.

As a frequent user of the Polars library, I'm looking to reliably read and write these attributes using the built-in Parquet implementation from polars.

Comment: I think that's "Parquet Metdata"? I don't think Polars allows that yet. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7854 - Also in the general case https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5117

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a feature like that in Polars at the moment